# CVXR: subsetting certain variables

Tags: r, cvxr

```
library("CVXR");
A <- Variable(3,3);
D <- matrix(c(A[1,1],0,0,0,A[2,2],0,0,0,A[3,3]),nrow=3);
A-D
```

Here, we have a matrix of variables, `A` (I am not sure if this is how to call the object correctly), and `D` as a matrix of variables, in which the diagonal consists of the diagonal of `A`, and everything else is `0.00`.
I would like to be able to set constraints such as `(A-D)%*%x == y`,
as one would normally do, e.g. `A%*%x == y` would work fine.
However, `R` does not seem to like `A-D` -- "s4 object is not subtractable". How to go about this?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do:

```
B <- Variable(3,3)
```

and add the constraints `B[1,1] == 0`, `B[2,2] == 0`, `B[3,3] == 0`, `B %*% x == y`.